# insert or update in postgresql 9.1

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

I have a bunch of insert statements with varying number of columns for their respective tables, i need to execute these queries if the record doesn't already exist.I have tried to implement this as

```
do $$
begin
IF not exists (SELECT 1 FROM gst_type_customer WHERE name = 'Unregistered') THEN
insert into gst_type_customer(create_date,write_date,create_uid,write_uid,name) values((now() at time zone 'UTC'),(now() at time zone 'UTC'),1,1,'Unregistered');
END IF;
end
$$
```

even though the above code does work although implementing for a bulk of queries would require a lot of time, so i thought of making a stored procedure which i could call as

```
merge_check(insertquery,name[column to check for duplication],value)
```

but I'm unable to execute the insert query directly.

so far I have come up with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION merge_tabla(data text)
RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  execute(data);
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql


select merge_table("insert into gst_type_customer(name) values('Unregistered')")
```

but I get an error saying

> column "insert into gst_type_customer(name) values('Unregistered')" does not exist

Comment: How about `INSERT INTO xxx SELECT ... values to be inserted ... WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM xxx WHERE ... existence condition...)`?

Comment: thank you for the reply,

Comment: thank you for the reply, isn't it like the code above that checks if it exists if it doesn't then it inserts, that code snippet works fine, could u give me an example if i'm not understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error You are getting is caused by using double quotes when calling the function. This should work:

```
select merge_table(E'insert into gst_type_customer(name) values(\'Unregistered\')'::text)
```

You need to use single quotes (double quotes are used for column names, single quotes for string literals) and escape any single quotes in the original query string.

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

You can use `INSERT ... SELECT` like this:

```
INSERT INTO gst_type_customer(create_date, write_date, create_uid, write_uid, name) 
SELECT (now() at time zone 'UTC'), (now() at time zone 'UTC'), 1, 1, 'Unregistered'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM gst_type_customer
    WHERE name = 'Unregistered'
)
```

Comment: that does work for a single query although i cannot implement the same for every query is it possible to implement the same in a stored procedure ?

Answer (score 1):

postgres 9.1 supports merge command
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/attachment/23520/sql-merge.html

sample:

```
MERGE CustomerAccount CA

USING (SELECT CustomerId, Sum(TransactionValue) As TransactionSum
       FROM Transactions
       WHERE TransactionId > 35345678
       GROUP BY CustomerId) AS T

ON T.CustomerId = CA.CustomerId

WHEN MATCHED 
  UPDATE SET Balance = Balance - TransactionSum

WHEN NOT MATCHED
  INSERT (CustomerId, Balance)
  VALUES (T.CustomerId, T.TransactionSum)
;
```